# Performantly filter against a custom time-like property

Tags: org-mode, performance

My agenda view processes many items with `SCHEDULED` and `DEADLINE` fields, and fully generates from scratch in about 0.3s. However, if I append `CUSTOM_SCHEDULED<"<now>"` to my agenda view definition, the same view takes 2.1s to generate. How can I add a custom time-like property in a way that does not wreck the performance of the view?

**Profiler excerpt:**

```
- org-tags-view                                  904  97%
 - org-scan-tags                                 888  95%
  - #<lambda 0x5be5aafca262231>                  838  90%
   - and                                         838  90%
    - progn                                      838  90%
     - or                                        837  90%
      - and                                      835  89%
       - not                                     835  89%
        - org-time<                              833  89%
         - or                                    831  89%
          - org-cached-entry-get                 831  89%
           - org-entry-properties                822  88%
```

As you can see, there is an explicit `org-time<` call that is causing the slowdown. What's interesting is that `SCHEDULED` and `DEADLINE` properties appear to use some other mechanism, since they do not cause the same hot loop in `org-time<`.

Comment: Have you [profiled](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html#Profiling) it?

Comment: @NickD Good idea. I've included an excerpt from the profiler that highlights the distinction between built-in and custom properties.

Comment: Matching properties other than the special ones (e.g. `SCHEDULED`) has always been slow (another example [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/37796/speed-up-org-map-entries-when-matching-by-property))